# java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=200, result=0, data=null} java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android

My app allows the user to press a button, it opens the camera for video capturing, they can take a video and it will show up in sdcard. If the user presses stop while the camera is open I get this force close - Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=200, result=0, data=null} to activity.
the application crashes whenever I stop recording a video.However the videos are stored in the directory, and use the same file naming formats.

this is activity class

```
public class VideocameraActivity extends Activity {

private Uri fileUri;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
private static final int CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
public static VideocameraActivity ActivityContext =null; 
public static TextView output;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.observation);

    ActivityContext = this;

    ImageView buttonRecording = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.add_rowBtn);
    //output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.output);

    buttonRecording.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // create new Intentwith with Standard Intent action that can be
            // sent to have the camera application capture an video and return it. 
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

            // create a file to save the video
            fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO); 

            // set the image file name  
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);  

            // set the video image quality to high
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1); 

            // start the Video Capture Intent
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

        }});


}

/** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){

      return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){

    // Check that the SDCard is mounted
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
              Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraVideo");


    // Create the storage directory(MyCameraVideo) if it does not exist
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){

        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){

            output.setText("Failed to create directory MyCameraVideo.");

            Toast.makeText(ActivityContext, "Failed to create directory MyCameraVideo.", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Log.d("MyCameraVideo", "Failed to create directory MyCameraVideo.");
            return null;
        }
    }


    // Create a media file name

    // For unique file name appending current timeStamp with file name
    java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                         .format(date.getTime());

    File mediaFile;

    if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {

        // For unique video file name appending current timeStamp with file name
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
        "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");

    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    // After camera screen this code will executed

    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            //output.setText("Video File : " +data.getData());

            // Video captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
            Toast.makeText(this, "Video saved to:\n" +
                     data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } /*else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

            output.setText("User cancelled the video capture.");

            // User cancelled the video capture
            Toast.makeText(this, "User cancelled the video capture.", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {

            output.setText("Video capture failed.");

            // Video capture failed, advise user
            Toast.makeText(this, "Video capture failed.", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }*/
    }
}

}
```

Log Cat Error:

```
11-07 06:48:59.062: D/dalvikvm(1585): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 71K, 6% free 2869K/3048K, paused 9ms, total 10ms
11-07 06:48:59.074: I/dalvikvm-heap(1585): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.069MB for 4367372-byte allocation
11-07 06:48:59.090: D/dalvikvm(1585): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 7134K/7316K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
11-07 06:48:59.174: D/dalvikvm(1585): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 3% free 7610K/7776K, paused 6ms, total 6ms
11-07 06:48:59.206: D/dalvikvm(1585): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5K, 2% free 9140K/9300K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
11-07 06:48:59.562: D/libEGL(1585): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
11-07 06:48:59.562: D/(1585): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb95313a8, tid 1585
11-07 06:48:59.570: D/libEGL(1585): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
11-07 06:48:59.570: D/libEGL(1585): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
11-07 06:48:59.606: W/EGL_genymotion(1585): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-07 06:48:59.610: E/OpenGLRenderer(1585): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
11-07 06:48:59.610: E/OpenGLRenderer(1585): MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
11-07 06:48:59.614: E/OpenGLRenderer(1585): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
11-07 06:48:59.614: E/OpenGLRenderer(1585): MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
11-07 06:48:59.614: D/OpenGLRenderer(1585): Enabling debug mode 0
11-07 06:49:14.386: W/EGL_genymotion(1585): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-07 06:49:34.218: D/dalvikvm(1585): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 645K, 7% free 10544K/11296K, paused 9ms, total 19ms
11-07 06:49:38.050: W/EGL_genymotion(1585): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-07 06:49:38.614: I/System.out(1585): Url--------login--> http://ilearniteasy.com/new-version/api/get_login.php?salt=8006&sign=85db4eebea8fca6814ad73a75efcdbf5&site_url=http://www.mydistance-learning-college.com/students/&username=teststudent7&password=password1
11-07 06:49:38.730: W/EGL_genymotion(1585): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-07 06:49:40.362: I/Choreographer(1585): Skipped 97 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-07 06:49:44.230: D/dalvikvm(1585): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 240K, 5% free 12079K/12676K, paused 3ms, total 15ms
11-07 06:49:44.278: W/EGL_genymotion(1585): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-07 06:49:59.114: W/EGL_genymotion(1585): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-07 06:50:02.946: W/EGL_genymotion(1585): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.ilearniteasy.VideocameraActivity.onActivityResult(VideocameraActivity.java:132)` What line is this?

Comment: Try to have data!=null check in your onActivityResult

Comment: app crash in 2.3 device on stop the video and take to the app and  the videos are stored in the directory

Answer (score 0):

Please check

```
if(data!=null) {

...

}
```

Comment: i edit my logcat now app is working fine in 4.4 device but crash on 2.3 android device when stop the video while camera is open and take to the app and video also save in sdcard. i cant figure it out how i resolve it